# Checking a solution to a separable differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In my textbook it is stated that the differential equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{d} t}=\left(x(t)\right)^{1/3}, \quad x(0)=0,
\end{equation}
has the solution $x_{2}(t)=\left(\frac{2}{3}t\right)^{3/2}$. I tried to verify that this indeed is a solution by:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d} x_{2}}{\mathrm{d} t}=t^{1/2}
\end{equation}
but:
\begin{equation}
\left(x_{2}(t)\right)^{1/3}=\left(\left(\frac{2}{3}t\right)^{3/2}\right)^{1/3}=\left(\frac{2}{3}t\right)^{1/2}.
\end{equation}
So $\frac{\mathrm{d} x_{2}}{\mathrm{d} t}\neq\left(x_{2}(t)\right)^{1/3}$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Notice that when you differetiate x, the (2/3) are included in the parentheses with t so it should be (⅔t)^½

Comment: Note that for $x_2(t)$ the factor of $\frac{2}{3}$ is *inside* the parentheses and affected by the $\frac{3}{2}$ power. This means you'll need to apply the chain rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\operatorname dx/\operatorname dt=x^{1/3}\implies x^{-1/3} \operatorname dx=\operatorname dt\implies3/2 x^{2/3} =t+C\implies x=(2/3(t+C))^{3/2}$.

Initial condition $x(0)=0\implies C=0$.

Actually I think it's not so much the chain rule you forgot, as just that the $2/3$ in front of the $t$ disappeared.

Let's check it:. $x'(t)=3/2(2/3t)^{1/2}(2/3)=(2/3t)^{1/2}=(x(t))^{1/3}$.